# ComboBox autocomplete strange behaviour

Tags: wpf, autocomplete

Bear with me. I have a ComboBox (WPF) in 'autocomplete' mode. 
Easy peasy right? Just set IsEditable to true.

```
<ComboBox 
    IsEditable="True"
    Text="{Binding Model.TextEntered}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Model.ListWithOptions}"/>
```

I've got my ComboBox and it autocomplete's just perfect.

BUT when I enter the following text 'caaaaa' it changes it to 'CAaaaa'. I understand the ComboBox autocomplete's the text and match the casing. But when I want to enter caaaaa (for whatever reason) I don't want 'CAaaaa'.

Any idea to solve this?

As an alternative I would settle for (if all else fails):

- When leaving the control, check if entered text doesn't match any of the options set text tolower. (as a behaviour)

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried setting `ShouldPreserveUserEnteredPrefix="True"`? This will not alter the case that is typed into the `Combobox` but will still match items in the list. So in your example if you type 'ca13' it will find and select 'CA132S', but it will be displayed in the combobox as 'ca132s' (in the case that it was typed in).

A compromise in the way that the item is displayed perhaps, but it will select the correct item and allow you to type characters in either case without alteration.

Comment: Excellent. Been looking for this one a long time, why didn't I spot this :(. Thanks Richard

Comment: This property is only supported in .NET 4.5. Is there any equivalent property in .NET 4.0?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting **IsTextSearchCaseSensitive** proprty to true for the ComboBox. Not sure if this property is available in older versions of .NET

Comment: It is available. It solves the casing problem, but auto-complete is now case sensitive which is unacceptable.

Comment: Guess, I misunderstood your question. You want it to be case sensitive. Don't you? How else is 'caaaaa' different from aCAaaaa'

Comment: Requirement 1) I need it to be case insensitive to find items in the list. Requirement 2) The user can type in a value that doesn't appear in the list. So when typing just 'ca' the caption goes to 'CA' because it combo finds 'CA132S', when the user keeps typing on to enter 'caaaaa' it becomes 'CAaaaa'.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you use an if statement to check if it matches anything in the list and if it doesn't, don't change it?  Like check after each letter entered and if it then doesn't match change it back to the case that was originally entered?

Or is there a reason you want people to be able to type in something that isn't in the list?  If not, couldn't you use IsTextSearchEnabled rather than IsEditable?

Comment: Hi Kat, I wan't the combobox to be autocomplete and also let the user add a string which isn't in the list.

Comment: @RalfdeKleine You COULD try swapping autocomplete for IsTextSearchEnabled ... I don't see why it wouldn't work for a combobox... I know on a game I play there is a dropdown list that if you open the list and start typing it goes to the first match in the list... I don't see why it wouldn't work while also showing what the user types... cause it seems like your problem is the autocomplete part that is changing the text in the box trying to match what's in the box... I don't know for sure, but I THINK IsTextSearchEnabled will do what you want.